# How to concatenate a fixed string and a variable in Python

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I want to include a file name, 'main.txt', in the subject. For that I am passing a file name from the command line. But I get an error in doing so:

```
python sample.py main.txt # Running 'python' with an argument

msg['Subject'] = "Auto Hella Restart Report "sys.argv[1]  # Line where I am using that passed argument
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to include the stack trace - it's there to help you debug!

Comment: That was four years after Stack Overflow launched. What is the canonical question? This must have been asked within the first few days.

Comment: The error message may be something like *"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"*.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm guessing that you meant to do this:

```
msg['Subject'] = "Auto Hella Restart Report " + sys.argv[1]
# To concatenate strings in Python, use       ^
```

Answer (score 27):

Using [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) which were introduced in Python version 3.6:

```
msg['Subject'] = f'Auto Hella Restart Report {sys.argv[1]}'
```

Comment: Is this the recommended way over the `plus` concatenator?

Comment: Just what I'm looking for now! Thank you!

Comment: What is the name of the Python feature used here? [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions)?

Comment: This *seems* to repeat [Doryx's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348717/how-to-concatenate-a-fixed-string-and-a-variable-in-python/57174458#57174458) (five months prior). What is the difference? Is there a real difference? (Single quotes vs. double quotes.)

Comment: No difference in single or double quotes, most people like to use double quotes in strings so that if you have an apostrophe you don't have to escape it, `"I'm Doryx"` instead of `'I\'m Doryx'`

Answer (score 13):

```
variable=" Hello..."
print (variable)
print("This is the Test File " + variable)
```

For an integer type:

```
variable = "  10"
print (variable)
print("This is the Test File " + str(variable))
```

Comment: But the question is not about integers, only two strings.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
msg['Subject'] = "Auto Hella Restart Report " + sys.argv[1]
```

The `+` operator is overridden in Python to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to add two strings, you have to use the '+' operator.

Hence

```
msg['Subject'] = 'your string' + sys.argv[1]
```

And also you have to import *sys* in the beginning.

As

```
import sys

msg['Subject'] = "Auto Hella Restart Report " + sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: It must be `msg['Subject'] = 'your string' + sys.argv[1]` in the first example otherwise you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

With Python 3.6 and later:

```
msg['Subject'] = f"Auto Hella Restart Report {sys.argv[1]}"
```

Comment: What is the name of the Python feature used here? [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions)?

Comment: Yes! Also see here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/ for the terminology. Thanks for the edit by the way!