# How to set name of text input in HTML form to be variable

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am trying to create text input in my HTML form but want that input to have name value set by variable:

```
#! c:\Python24\python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n" 

import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable()

name1 = "kuba"
val1 = 150
name2 = "pipi"
val2 = 300

print("<form action='python2.py' method='GET'>")
print("<input type='text' name='name1'>")
print("<input type=submit value='name2'>")
```

I would like to have my text to have name "kuba" and not "name1"

Can someone give me a hint?
Thank you,
Jakub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348717/how-to-use-concatenate-a-fixed-string-and-a-variable-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.format()` in your string like this, say `name1` is your variable that you want in your second print method. Then you would do:

```
#! c:\Python24\python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n" 

import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable()

name1 = "kuba"
val1 = 150
name2 = "pipi"
val2 = 300

print("<form action='python2.py' method='GET'>")
print("<input type='text' name='{0}'>".format(name1))
print("<input type=submit value='name2'>")
```

Hence the second `print()` would output `<input type='text' name='kuba'>` . 
As requested by OP, for python 2.4

```
print("<input type='text' name='%s'>"%name1)
```

Similarly you could use other concatination option like `+` as pointed by @Rafalsonn in the comment.

Comment: Oh, you're using python 2.4?

Comment: Yes...only thing available on my webhost :( Is there alternative for 2.4?

Comment: Oh Ok, can you please check my updated answer and see if it's work? I can't verify it on my system.