# How to pass value inside html content in django 2

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to create an appointment system where appointment system will send mail to the user where mail data will be dynamic but the problem is how cloud I pass data inside html_content like the date is a variable how can I pass date value inside Meeting Date + symbol is not working because mine is not string its an HTML code

Here is my Code

```
subject, from_email, to = 'You Have A Meeting Request', 'send@gmail.com', 'text@gmail.com'
text_content = 'Dear Sir,'
date = 12-12-2018
html_content = '<p>This is an ' \
               '<strong>Meeting Request</strong>' \
               ' <ul>' \
               '<li><b>Meeting Date:</b>  {{ date }}</li>' \
               '<li><strong>Meeting Place:</strong> DRL , Meeting Room 1</li>' \
               '<li><strong>Time:</strong> 10-30 To 13-30</li>' \
               '<li><strong>Meeting Purpose:</strong> For Opening Appointment</li>' \
               '<li><strong>No Of Person:</strong> 5</li>' \
               '<li><strong>Priority:</strong> High</li>' \
               '<li><strong>Request By:</strong> Mr X</li>' \
               '</ul>.</p>'

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use concatenate a fixed string and a variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348717/how-to-use-concatenate-a-fixed-string-and-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: No, that not help me cuz those are string but mine is HTML  + not work for me giving an error

Comment: There is no datatype in Python that is HTML in the way you describe it. The data in `html_content` is going to be a string that **will form HTML**, but it's still a string. The answer you accepted is exactly what the duplicate describes, just in another way of concatenating the variables into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do something like this:

```
html_content = '''
<p>This is an 
<strong>Meeting Request</strong>
<ul>
<li><b>Meeting Date:</b>  %s</li>
<li><strong>Meeting Place:</strong> DRL , Meeting Room 1</li>
<li><strong>Time:</strong> 10-30 To 13-30</li>
<li><strong>Meeting Purpose:</strong> For Opening Appointment</li>
<li><strong>No Of Person:</strong> 5</li>
<li><strong>Priority:</strong> High</li>
<li><strong>Request By:</strong> Mr X</li>
</ul>.</p>
''' % (date)
```