# How to enter senders name into email body

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to setup a script to send email, and I want to add the Senders Name (depending on who runs the script) to the Email Body.

Emailing works, and I'm setup on Juypter, runing Python 3, emailing from Outlook.

My code is below. The mail.SenderName is the part I want to pull the name from the Outlook account of the user. In VBA this would be equivalent to using Application.UserName

```py
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "user@somewhere.com"
mail.Subject = "Report"

#Text for email
mail.HTMLBody = "Dear All,<br><br>" \
"The latest version of the Report is attached in PDF format.<br><br>" \
"Kind Regards <br><br>" \
mail.SenderName

attachment  = filename
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

So I would want the email body to be:

> Dear All,
>   The latest version of the Report is attached in PDF format.
>   Kind Regards 
>   Bob Smith

Any help, much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
By combining the response from `Error - Syntactical Remorse` and `Eugene Astafiev`, with a bit more searching, I managed to resolve the issue. Thank you for the guidance.

Full code is:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "user@somewhere.com"
mail.Subject = "Report"

sender = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser.Name

#Text for email
mail.HTMLBody = "Dear All,<br><br>" \
"The latest version of the Report is attached in PDF format.<br><br>" \
"Kind Regards <br><br>" \
f"{sender}"

attachment  = filename
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Use string formatting. Something like `f"Sent from {mail.SenderName}"` (In Python2.7 you need to us `%` string formatting).

Comment: Or just `str(mail.SenderName)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348717/how-to-use-concatenate-a-fixed-string-and-a-variable-in-python

Comment: The `f"{mail.SenderName}"` line looks like it is trying to work, but I think it is not actually able to get my name from my outlook account. (Basically I get a blank space where my name should be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Use the [NameSpace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object.

```
      Sub DisplayCurrentUser()  
        Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
        Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
        MsgBox myNameSpace.CurrentUser.Name  
      End Sub
```

2. If it is set, you may use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1390)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property which returns an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

```
     MailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Python at all.

Comment: This looks like VBA, and I have no problem doing this in VBA. The question is about Python3.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages. I just showed the sequence of property and method calls to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks - managed to work out how to use this in my code. And learnt a bit more about how it works along the way.